# NullPointerException when starting Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

When I click a item (that opens ItemActivity) in the list of ListTabActivity, the program crashs.

Log:

```
12-06 22:00:45.196: D/ListTabActivity(1479): Start onItemClick() // It's in ListTabActivity
12-06 22:00:45.227: D/ListTabActivity(1479): End onItemClick() // too
12-06 22:00:48.026: D/ItemActivity(1479): Sets 2 - Case 2 Start // It's in ItemAcitivity
12-06 22:00:48.046: W/System.err(1479): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 22:00:48.067: W/System.err(1479):     at tbf.tartarugaburguer.simulador1o1.ItemActivity.onCreate(ItemActivity.java:45)
12-06 22:00:48.097: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-06 22:00:48.126: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-06 22:00:48.136: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-06 22:00:48.156: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-06 22:00:48.176: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-06 22:00:48.226: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-06 22:00:48.246: W/System.err(1479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 22:00:48.266: W/System.err(1479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 22:00:48.288: W/System.err(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-06 22:00:48.316: W/System.err(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 22:00:48.356: W/System.err(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 22:00:48.376: W/System.err(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-06 22:00:48.396: W/System.err(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-06 22:00:48.426: W/System.err(1479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 22:46:11.416: D/AndroidRuntime(1840): Shutting down VM
12-06 22:46:11.416: W/dalvikvm(1840): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tbf.tartarugaburguer.simulador1o1/tbf.tartarugaburguer.simulador1o1.ItemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at tbf.tartarugaburguer.simulador1o1.ItemActivity.onCreate(ItemActivity.java:49)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-06 22:46:11.508: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     ... 11 more
```

ListTabActivity class:
(It opens, but when it open the ItemActivity, the program crashs)

```
public class ListTabActivity extends Activity {
    static int tabNum;
    static int position;
    static List<Item>   itemList1,
                        itemList2,
                        itemList3,
                        itemList4;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int resource = 0;
        if(extras != null) {
            tabNum = extras.getInt("tab");
            resource = extras.getInt("resource");
        }

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        ItemParser itemParser = new ItemParser();
        itemParser.parse(inputStream);

        switch (tabNum) {
        default:
        case 1:
            itemList1 = itemParser.getList(); break;
        case 2:
            itemList2 = itemParser.getList(); break;
        case 3:
            itemList3 = itemParser.getList(); break;
        case 4:
            itemList4 = itemParser.getList();
        }

        ItemArrayAdapter adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, itemParser.getList(), tabNum);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                ListTabActivity.position = position;

                Log.d("ListTabActivity", "Start onItemClick()");

                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ListTabActivity.this, ItemActivity.class));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("ListTabActivity", "End onItemClick()");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ItemActivity:

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity {
    int tabNum,
        itemAmount,
        position;
    List<Item> itemList;
    TextView tvTotal;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_item);

        tabNum  = ListTabActivity.tabNum;
        position    = ListTabActivity.position;
        itemAmount  = MainActivity.buyItems[tabNum - 2][position];

        String itemPhoto;
        switch (ListTabActivity.tabNum) {
        default:
        case 2:
            itemList = ListTabActivity.itemList1;
            Log.d("ItemActivity", "Sets 2 - Case 2 Start");

            try {
                itemPhoto = "images/tab2/photo/" + itemList.get(position).photoId; //break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                itemPhoto = "images/tab2/photo/" + itemList.get(position).photoId; //break;
            }

            Log.d("ItemActivity", "Sets 2 - Case 2 End"); break;
        case 3:
            itemList = ListTabActivity.itemList2;
            itemPhoto = "images/tab3/photo/" + itemList.get(position).photoId; break;
        case 4:
            itemList = ListTabActivity.itemList3;
            itemPhoto = "images/tab4/photo/" + itemList.get(position).photoId; break;
        case 5:
            itemList = ListTabActivity.itemList4;
            itemPhoto = "images/tab5/photo/" + itemList.get(position).photoId; break;
        }


        final TextView  tvDescription,
                        tvPrice,
                        tvAmount;
        final ImageView ivPhoto;

        tvDescription=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_description);
        tvPrice     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        tvAmount    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_amount);
        tvTotal     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        ivPhoto     = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_photo);

        tvDescription.setText(itemList.get(position).description);
        tvPrice.setText("R$ " + itemList.get(position).price);
        tvAmount.setText(itemAmount);
        tvTotal.setText(0);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getResources().getAssets().open(itemPhoto));
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you showing the entire log? And what's on line 45 in ItemActivity?

Comment: What is at line 49 of `ItemActivity`?

Comment: "final TextView  tvDescription,", codeMagic?
A TextView =/ Wanna see the xml?

Comment: Are you sure? Because its impossible for that line to throw a `NPE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `ItemAcitivity` case 2, the below code would be `null`

```
itemList.get(position).photoId
```

print it out and check the object `itemList` if is `null`.

or

in the `TabActivity` case 1

```
itemList1 = itemParser.getList();
```

will be `null`

Comment: Thanks! itemList1 was null.